# How to store time in C++

Tags: c++, networking, time

I'm developing an application and need to store, process and sync time with the server application.
I don't know how to practically store time using C++, I was thinking about creating a dedicated class or storing it in a Unix-like fashion.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: see [`std::chrono`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono)

Comment: You need to decide whether you're using C or C++, the answers are very different for each.

Comment: C++ has some great time facilities. C not so much. Check [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) and become informed.

Comment: C'mon gang! what's wrong with good ol'  `time_t`? I *love* having a timer with an unspecified period, datatype and epoch.

Answer (score 1):

C++ has chrono library, you can read more in the following link
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/

But the below code will print the current time to screen:

```
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
std::time_t t_c = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now);
std::cout << std::ctime(&t_c);
```

Output:

```
Fri Aug 21 02:10:55 2020
```

If you need a specific format of time, please update the post, I hope it will be useful